# JaxbContext object is being created again

Tags: rest, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am calling the REST API as below,

```
  String uri = "http://localhost:8080/jd/rest/emp/getEmp";
    EmpRequest request = new EmpRequest();
    //set id as 1 for OK response
    request.setId(2);
    request.setName("PK");
    try{
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource r=client.resource(uri);
    ClientResponse response = r.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(ClientResponse.class,request );
    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
    if(response.getStatus() == 200){
        EmpResponse empResponse = response.getEntity(EmpResponse.class);
        System.out.println(empResponse.getId() + "::"+empResponse.getName());
    }else{
        ErrorResponse exc = response.getEntity(ErrorResponse.class);
        System.out.println(exc.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println(exc.getErrorId());
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Here, it is taking a long time to send the request. I suspect that is because it is making a new JAXB object every time. Is there a way I can use the same JAXB object in this approach?

I have put the time after each steps in local file. It seems to take the most time in this step (almost 15 sec)

```
  ClientResponse response = r.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(ClientResponse.class,request );
```

Comment: Can you show us the webservice code?

Comment: And what is `EmpRequest` and `EmpResponse`?

Comment: you mean server side? I am using a 3rd party webservice.

Comment: You deploy an external webservice file on your app server, right? If so, you can't control, what happens on server side.

Comment: I meant, the webservice are written by other website and we call their URL. It gives the response in almost 2-3s from fiddler.   I have edited the question.

Comment: In your code you call `localhost`. Or does your webservice at localhost call another webservice??

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting you call a webservice, you don't own, you won't be able to control how (and when) it will react.

That will be the reason why your call

```
r.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(ClientResponse.class, request);
```

takes a long time.